# How to check a date is between two data ranges on multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of dates, and need a column that indicates whether it is within range of two dates on another sheet. However the kicker is that there are multiple rows on Sheet 2 for the same ID, I need to check if the first row is within range, then if not, when the next row where ID matches.

Sheet 1

```
[Date]     [ID]   [IsWithinDate]
25-09-2019  4          Yes
```

Sheet 2

```
[Start]     [End]      [ID]
19-08-2019  19-09-2019  4
19-09-2019  19-10-2019  4
```

I expect the outcome for [IsWithinDate] to check the first row, where ID matches, and check that [Date] is between [Start] and [End]. The first row it is not within range, however on row 2 (Sheet 2) it is within range. How do i check multiple rows?

Comment: This might be better answered with vba. How comfortable are you with that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any guess?

Comment: @JackArmstrong Not familiar unfortunately

Comment: @TerryW Honestly, not too sure where to start with this. I might import it into a SQL db, if i can not get it to work within excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Solution]

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Start** being all starting dates on your sheet2;
- **End** being all ending dates on your sheet2;
- **ID** being all IDs on your sheet2.

You can use **COUNTIFS** to get the answer:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Start,"<="&A3,End,">="&A3,ID,B3)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Change the cell references as desired. Cheers :)

Comment: This worked very well, nice clean formula. Thank you! clearly i must read up more on named ranges.

Comment: @Vine you are very welcome. **Named Range** is very effective for working across worksheets, and help self-explaining a formula. Just an advice next time when asking a question please do let people know what you've tried or at least explain why you are unable to come up with a clue at that stage. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(SUM((B2=Sheet2!C:C)*(A2>=Sheet2!A:A)*(A2<=Sheet2!B:B))>0,"Yes","No")
```

`(B2=Sheet2!C:C)`, `(A2>=Sheet2!A:A)` and `(A2<=Sheet2!B:B)` return Arrays of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  Multiplied together, returns an array of `1`'s (date is in the range) and `0`'s date is NOT in the range).  `SUM`'d, if `>0` then the date is in at least one of the ranges, with matching ID .

<sub>Assumes [Start] and [End] are columns A, B</sub>